# ssl Exclamation mark

Tags: ssl

I configure SSL in Terminal in Ubuntu on my site and https works but there is an exclamation mark says that the connection not secure! with a message mixed content.

so how do I correct this and is ssl works as it should be?

Comment: What message is shown? There are thousands of reasons why SSL doesn't work. Please [edit] your post and include the reason for the exclamation mark. Reasons might be: wrong certificate, unknown CA, wrong domain name, certificate expired, mixed content, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your site is served over HTTPS, there are many things that are checked to ensure the connection is secure.

One of the requirements is that all contents of the page that are loaded are loaded from HTTPS.  This means that your page cannot have any non-HTTPS files loaded (including `.js`, `.png`, `.css`, etc).  You can have `<a href=` that point to non-HTTPS, but your page cannot otherwise source non-HTTPS files.  When you see "Mixed Content", this is the problem you need to fix.

It is important to understand why this is.  For example, if I visit your site and it says it's HTTPS, but you send the login credentials over HTTP, then your site is obviously not secure.